# How to save sqlite database in resources folder android?

Tags: android, sqlite

Hello i am following this tutorial [Using your own SQLite database in Android applications](http://www.reigndesign.com/blog/using-your-own-sqlite-database-in-android-applications/)

Now i don't understand how is save in first place created database. Here is the code how sqlite is taken from resources folder:

```
InputStream myInput = myContext.getAssets().open(DB_NAME);
```

So where to keep in first place my sqlite as if i copy in resources folder i get compiler error:

```
invalid resource directory name
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As what i did in one of my project, copy your database file in `raw` folder and get its `InputStream` as below:

```
InputStream myInput = myContext.getResources().openRawResource(DB_NAME);
```

now copy **myInput** stream contents to a cache directory in order to create a copy of your database file.

Further you may use that database file with `SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase` to get `SQLiteDatabase` object and do your sql magic

Answer (score 1):

In your Activity.java you need to setup your DB

```
 private void setupDatabase() {
                Dbhelper myDbHelper = new Dbhelper(getApplicationContext());
                myDbHelper = new Dbhelper(this);

                try {

                    myDbHelper.createDataBase();

                } catch (IOException ioe) {

                    throw new Error("Unable to create database");

                }

            }
```